# Object wrapper/parameter injection module

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I made an object wrapper/parameter injector and I hope it will be useful. I made it for a project I am working on but then decided to try polishing it a bit.

The use case is for wrapping objects such that you can inject parameters into their methods by calling the wrapper as a function. I was heavily inspired by AngularJS and their use of parameter injection to almost create a DSL with their framework.

Questions:

1. Is this a well-designed module?
2. Is my code legible?
3. Am I over looking something that might lead to bugs later?
4. Is something like this safe to use?

[Repo](https://github.com/KGZM/negotiator.js)

**negotiator.js**

```
# A small tool for proxying objects behind a wrapper that can inject
# parameters into their methods.

# Extract parameter names from a function,
# position is given by position this array.
if module
  _ = require('underscore');
else
  _ = window._

utils = {};

utils.parameterNames = (func) ->

  funcArgs = func.toString().split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')

  return (k.trim() for k in funcArgs)


# Inject parameters from a context object into a function.
# Passed parameters are supplied by the 'params' argument.
utils.injectAndApply =(func, parameters, context, target) ->

  signature = utils.parameterNames func
  parameters = [] if _.isEmpty(parameters)

  for position, name of signature
    parameters[position] = context[name] if context[name]?

  parameters.length = signature.length;
  return func.apply target ? {}, parameters


# Constructor for proxy object.
utils.Proxy = (real) ->

  @$real = real
  self = this

  for key, method of real when typeof method is 'function'
    do (method, key) ->
      self[key] = ->
        utils.injectAndApply method, arguments, @$context ? {}, @$real

  return this


# Build a context object from an arguments list.
utils.buildContextFromParams = (func, parameters) ->
  signature = utils.parameterNames func
  context = {}
  for key, value of parameters
    context[signature[key]] = value

  return context


# This is the circular wrapper that returns a version of itself with
# a set context.
utils.innerWrapper = (proxy, templateFunction, parameters) ->
  wrapper = ->
    utils.innerWrapper(proxy,templateFunction,arguments);

  context = utils.buildContextFromParams templateFunction, parameters 
  context.$real = proxy.$real
  context.$wrapper = wrapper
  context.$proxy =  proxy
  context.$context = context;
  utils.injectAndApply templateFunction, parameters, context, proxy
  wrapper.$context = context;

  wrapper.__proto__ = proxy;

  return wrapper

# Returns a function that wraps object.
# not intended to be called as a constructor
utils.makeWrapper = (real, templateFunction) ->
  proxy = new utils.Proxy real

  return utils.innerWrapper proxy, templateFunction, []

negotiator = utils.makeWrapper
negotiator.utils = utils;

if module
  module.exports = negotiator
else
  window.negotiator = negotiator

return
```

Comment: I don't know if this is useful advice but you could use some common CoffeeScript conventions like implicit returns, and `=>` to bind a function to the current value of `this`. You also don't need to end lines with semicolons. I highlighted some of these with `#CR:` in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/wildlyinaccurate/5021863

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks quite good.
Nevertheless here are some thoughts:

### Parameter Names

You might get problems when calling `utils.parameterNames` without arguments. E.g. `func.toString()` would fail if `func` is undefined.
Moreover you'll get an array with one entry  (`['']`) if you pass a function with no arguments (`utils.parameterNames(->)`) where you might expect an empty array.
You could change your implementation to this:

```
utils.parameterNames = (func=->) ->
  funcArgs = func.toString().split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')
  (t for k in funcArgs when (t=k.trim()) isnt '')
```

Here is an other implementation ([source](https://github.com/flosse/scaleApp/blob/master/src/Util.coffee)) using an regular expression

```
getArgumentNames = (fn=->) ->
  args = fn.toString().match ///
    function # start with 'function'
    [^(]* # any character but not '('
    \( # open bracket = '(' character
    ([^)]*) # any character but not ')'
    \) # close bracket = ')' character
  ///
return [] if not args? or (args.length < 2)
args = args[1]
args = args.split /\s*,\s*/
(a for a in args when a.trim() isnt '')
```

We could also write s.th. like this:

```
fnRgx = ///
  function # start with 'function'
  [^(]* # any character but not '('
  \( # open bracket = '(' character
  ([^)]*) # any character but not ')'
  \) # close bracket = ')' character
///

argRgx = /([^\s,]+)/g

parameterNames = (fn) ->
  (fn?.toString().match(fnRegex)?[1] or '').match(argRgx) or []
```

The performance depend on the browser but the last one seems to be pretty fast (see [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/getparameternames))

### Expressions

In CoffeeScript every thing is an expression so you can turn this

```
if module
  _ = require('underscore');
else
  _ = window._
```

into this

```
_ = if module then require('underscore') else window._
```

### Iteration

This:

```
for position, name of signature
  parameters[position] = context[name] if context[name]?
```

could also be written in that way:

```
for position, name of signature when context[name]?
  parameters[position] = context[name]
```

or even:

```
parameters[position] = context[name] for position, name of signature when context[name]?
```

It compiles all to the same JS. I'd prefer the second variant.